# How to create an ec2 instances for ECS cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

How do I create an ec2 instances that is compatible and can be added to an empty ECS cluster. Is there an existing Image avaliabe that I can use? or Do I create an vm from scratch and install if so what all do I need to setup in the ec2 instance.

Answer (score 1):

Use one of the [ECS optimized AMIs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-optimized_AMI.html). IT will come with everything preinstalled.

Once this has been done you'll need to add the ECS instance to the cluster. Instructions here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/launch_container_instance.html